# Obtain one property of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{id, name, time}, {id, name, time}, {id, name, time}..]
```

What I need is to obtain the time of every object, but individualy. I try using map fuction but it returns an array of times and I need each time individual.

**EDIT 1:**

The expexted output is:

```
1431964260000
1431962460000
1431961860000
1431961860000
1431961260000
```

Every one is an individual time.

I've use this code:

```
var date = data.map(function(obj){
          var rObj;
          rObj = obj.time;
          return rObj;
          console.log(rObj);
        });
```

But it's return:

```
 [1431964260000,
    1431962460000,
    1431961860000,
    1431961860000,
    1431961260000]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a foreach loop?

Assuming your array is assigned to a variable named `birthdays`

```
 birthdays.forEach( function(day) {
      console.log(day.time);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try this but returns, TypeError: data.mapIndividual is not a function.

Comment: I made you a little jsFiddle   
This should help:  
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apcjfr7z/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop in an array with the [`forEach` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) :

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}].forEach(function(item) {
  //You can access directly to object properties
  console.log(item.time)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom mapIndividual function:

```
Array.prototype.mapIndividual = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(this, i, this[i].time);
        }
    }.bind(this), 0);
};

obj.mapIndividual(function(index, time){
    console.log(index + ' ' + time);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/oc9f0323/)